# Adding sliders in specific pages

Tags: drupal-7, slider

I am new to drupal, I created a theme using mother ship and added slider to the front page using the code. my issue is i need to add the same slider in another page also. Can some one help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to admin/structure/block, configure link next to the block with the slider, then you can set an option to either 1) display on every page except... or 2) display only on these pages. Enter the path (node/233) or path alias, one per line, in the textarea below the option radios.

Alternatively, you can use the Context module (http://drupal.org/project/context)

Comment: thank you for your response. my page is a page view(/services) and slider is a block view. and i need the slider to appear on front page and services which is the view. can you help me fix this?

Comment: In the admin/structure/block (d7) or admin/build/block (d6) find the block and click on "configure." In the configure screenm scroll down to where you see the radio buttons that say "Show only on the listed pages." Check that, and then in the textfield below enter on line one, <front>. One line two enter "services" and on line three enter "services/*" if you want to show it on subsequent "services/path/to/whatever pages.